# Does SWIG have support for finalization blocks?

Tags: swig

SWIG has support for including code that is executed when loading a module, as follows:

```
%init %{
    init_variables();
%}
```

Does something similar also exist for finalization? I can not find any documentation on it, maybe there is another good way to achieve the same thing for finalization?

Comment: modules aren't typically unloaded.  What are you trying to do?

Comment: Whenever a Python script exits that has imported a module generated by SWIG it would be nice if some kind of finalization code could be run. Now, we have to explicitly add a finalization method to our API.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could register an `atexit` cleanup routine during `%init`.  Here's a working sample:

```
%module sample

%{
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void cleanup()
{
    printf("cleanup!\n");
}
%}

%init %{
    atexit(cleanup);
%}
```

Result:

```
Python 3.3.0 (v3.3.0:bd8afb90ebf2, Sep 29 2012, 10:57:17) [MSC v.1600 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sample
>>> ^Z

cleanup!
```